# CSS problem with padding shorthand vs 4 line code

Tags: html, css

first of all, thx for coming here, Today I encountered a very strange CSS behaviour as you can see in the snippet:

```
/* padding: 0.5rem,2rem,0.5rem,2rem; this line is not working*/
/* while these do:*/
padding-top: 0.5rem;
padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
padding-right: 2rem;
padding-left: 2rem;
```

can somebody explain me why? BTW I am styling buttons using this code

full styling of button:

```css
.banner__button{
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 0.2vw;
    /* padding: 0.5rem,2rem,0.5rem,2rem; */
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: `padding: 0.5rem,2rem,0.5rem,2rem` – those commas don’t belong in there, correct would be `padding: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem`

Comment: @CBroe yeah! that's the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using shorthand syntax to define the [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) for an element, you don't need commas between each value. It should just be space separated like this:

```css
padding: top right bottom left;
```

```css
.banner__button{
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    border-radius: 0.2vw;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem;
    /*padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;*/
    margin-right: 1rem;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: bruh,i am dumb XD

Comment: @AneeqAk It's an honest mistake. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: @TannerDobly yea i will do

Answer (score 1):

You are adding wrong css. Please check below.

```css
div{ padding: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem;}

div{ padding-top: 0.5rem;
padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
padding-right: 2rem;
padding-left: 2rem; }
```

```html
<div style="height:100px;background:red;"></div>
```

you can add padding using above both way.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are putting commas between the values of different sides.

```
padding: 0.5rem 2rem 0.5rem 2rem;
```

will work. Let me know if you have any other issues.

Comment: yea thx haven't worked with CSS in a while